# Ionic WooCommerce - Cannot use namespace 'WooCommerceProvider' as a type

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to use the WooCommerce API to retrieve a list of products for my Ionic APP, and I've created a provider for that purpose, which contains the following

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Injectable()
export class WooCommerceProvider {
  Woocommerce: any;
  WoocommerceV2 : any;
  constructor() {

this.Woocommerce =  WC({
  url: 'https://colorvet.ro/wp-json/wc/v1/products',
  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  queryStringAuth: true,
  verifySsl: true,
  version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});




}
  init(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.Woocommerce;
});
}
}
```

I've replaced the consumer key and secret with my own. The following is the page where I try to receive the list of products:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';
import { WooCommerceProvider } from '../providers/woo-commerce/woo-commerce';

/**
 * Generated class for the ShopPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-shop',
  templateUrl: 'shop.html',
})
export class ShopPage {

  produse: any[];
  WooCommerce: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
     private alertCtrl: AlertController,private wooProvider: WooCommerceProvider ) {

      this.WooCommerce = wooProvider.WooCommerce;

      this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then((searchData) => {
        this.produse = JSON.parse(searchData.body).products;
      });

  }
```

> I get the following error : [ts] Cannot use namespace 'WooCommerceProvider' as a type.

Answer (score 1):

the import `import { WooCommerceProvider } from '../providers/woo-commerce/woo-commerce';` imports a namespace and not the concrete provider.

Look into the type file what's the name of the provider.